# How can I bind a store to Combobox

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How can I bind a store to Combobox by using combobox ID like:

`Ext.getCmp('combobox-id').store(unitStore);`

name of combpobox-"configuration-unit-form-select-Merge-with-unit"
store is-"unitStore"; IN extjs 3.4

Comment: Although the question may be clear to you, it is hard to understand what is being ask here. Could you possibly make it clearer so others can help you?

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

`Ext.getCmp('comboid').bindStore(unitStore);`

Thats the proper way of binding a store to an existent combo.

Answer (score 2):

Ext.getCmp(id) takes id as parameter not name so, that is the first change you should make. [Doc Link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp)

Considering configuration-unit-form-select-Merge-with-unit as an id property of Combo try below

```
Ext.getCmp('configuration-unit-form-select-Merge-with-unit').store.loadData(unitStore);
```